# React ternary operator issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning basics of React by doing examples on w3schools site: https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/react_conditional_rendering.asp

I understand example the way they did it, but i don't understand why it doesn't work when i change it to this:

```
    function Goal(props){
        const isGoal=props.isGoal;        
        
       isGoal ?  return <MadeGoal/> : return <MissedGoal/>       
    
    }
```

React is giving me 'Unexpected token' error.
They have similar example for 'if Statement' at the beggining of article that does work:

```
function Goal(props) {
  const isGoal = props.isGoal;
  if (isGoal) {
    return <MadeGoal/>;
  }
  return <MissedGoal/>;
}
```

So I don't understand what the issue is?

I have tried changing the example

Comment: use the return on the left side of `isGoal`. the ternary is an expression while `return` is a statement.

Comment: Single return, ternary after the return.

Comment: What previous commentators failed to mention is the reason why it works with if and it doesn't with ternary. Ternary operator explicitly returns value while if statement doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator can be thought of as a simplified version of the if-else statement with a value to be returned. It consists of a Boolean condition that evaluates to either true or false, along with a value that would be returned if the condition is true and another value if the condition is false.

You will have to remove the return statement from the ternary operator since the operation automatically returns a value by checking the condition.

```
function Goal(props){

   const isGoal=props.isGoal;         
   return isGoal ?  <MadeGoal/> : <MissedGoal/>       

}
```

Comment: "ternary operator can be thought of as a simplified version of the if-else statement " if that was true then upper example for 'if Statement' wouldn't work. Unlike ternary operator If statement version doesn't need return on the left side of it...